# call javascript object function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects of the same type.

```
function myObject(){
this.a = 1;
this.b = 1;
function changeA(){//some code};
function changeB(){//some code};
}

var obj1 = new myObject();
var obj2 = new myObject();
```

How can I make a call to obj2.changeB() from external code, another function or another object (e.g. obj1) ?

Comment: You can't, the functions are local and not part of the `myObject`

Comment: A local function is not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a properties in you object like:

```
function myObject(){
this.a = 1;
this.b = 1;
this.functionA = function changeA(){//some code
    alert('im 1');
};
this.functionb = function changeB(){//some code
alert('im 2');};
}
```

and call the function `obj2.functionb();`

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wilfredo1285/oamf3ead/)

Answer (score 3):

`obj2.changeB()` doesn't exist.

You need to assign a property on your object, not create a local variable:

```
this.changeB = function() { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

```
var myObject = function(){
var protectedValue1 = ‘variable’;
var protectedValue2 = ‘variable’;
var changeA = function(){
alert(protectedValue);
}
var changeB = function(){
alert(protectedValue);
}
}
var object1 = new myObject();
var object2 = new myObject();
//
object2.changeB();
```